# Reflection on podcast: improve the handling of chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, iphone

Listening to [the new Stack Exchange podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/11/podcast-61-the-what-jays-done-wrong-podcast/#comment-97016), they mentioned how chat was a pain on the iPhone app since it opened it into another app.

Why can't we just open it within a browser *inside* the app? When there is a link in the comments, it opens within **the app** (I love being able to chose Chrome!). Why can't it open in the app, also? That would make the UI much more streamlined.

If this is implemented, have it so the users are logged online automatically so I don't have to type my password twice.

Comment: Your proposed solution is... not quite the best idea IMO. Additionally it'd be nice to include the android-app into this, too... it suffers from the very same problem. In general using chat on mobile is a PITA